# How to edit woocommerce functions trought theme's functions?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to edit public function generate_product_data from woocommerce/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php

Inside this function:

```
    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        $markup['sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $markup['sku'] = $product->get_id();
    }
```

I want to change it to:

```
    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        $markup['sku'] = $product->get_sku();
        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $markup['sku'];
    } else {
        $markup['sku'] = $product->get_id();
        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $product->get_id();
    }
```

And i want to add my custom code right before this part:

```
            // Check we have required data.
            if ( empty( $markup['aggregateRating'] ) && empty( $markup['offers'] ) && empty( $markup['review'] ) ) {
                    return;
            }
```

I tried with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'add_mpn' );
function add_mpn($markup) {

                if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
                        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $markup['sku'];
                } else {
                        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $product->get_id();
                }

  return $markup;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to change it a bit. The filter gives you two variables to work with, although you need to return only one. This is why I added the priority (50) and the number 2, to accept two variables.

I also recommend to give a more meaningful name to your function. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'add_mpn', 50, 2 );
function add_mpn($markup, $product) {

                if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
                        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $markup['sku'];
                } else {
                        $markup['mpn'] = 'BG' . $product->get_id();
                }

  return $markup;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I forgot about priority. You helped me a lot.